On equations in finite fields with no more than one solution
Let $f: \mathbb{F}_{p^n}\setminus\{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{p^n}\setminus\{\beta\}$ be a bijection, where $\beta$ is some element of finite field of order $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ of order ${p^n}$.
I've stumbled upon some family of equations of form
$f(\alpha x)=\gamma f(x)$, where $\alpha,\gamma$ are non-zero and non-identity elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. And I want to find such function $f$, that all these equations for all non-zero and non-identity $\alpha,\gamma$ have no more than one solution.
I've found such family of $f$`s: they are of form $f(x)=x + \theta$, where '+' means addition in $\mathbb{F}_n$. Indeed, our equation transforms into:
$\alpha x+\theta =\gamma(x+\theta)$,
which is linear hence has no more than one solution. I'm interested in finding all such families or maybe to prove that the mentioned above family is the only one. I would appreciate any help.
Edit: case $\alpha=\gamma$ doesn't bring many solutions as it implies then that $\gamma$ is identity.

I don't understand what a "family" of these equations is. Can we only vary the elements $\alpha,\gamma$? Or do you mean a family $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ of such maps? For a finite field, one usually writes $\Bbb F_q$, where $q=p^n$ is a prime power. Can you make your question explicit for $\Bbb F_2$? Then $f$ is sending $1$ to $1$, so there is only one such $f$, which is a bijection.

I meant, that we could only vary $\alpha$ and $\gamma$, so I want to find such function $f$, that for all $\alpha$'s and $\gamma$'s the equations have no more than one solution

There is a problem with your family when $\alpha=\gamma$, in which case $\alpha x+\theta=\gamma(x+\theta)$ has either no solutions or plenty of them. Only you can tell, whether that is problem for the application you have in mind :-)

Is $\theta$ in your example the same as $\beta$ in your first sentence?

@JyrkiLahtonen  if $\alpha=\gamma$ and the equation has plenty solutions that implies $\gamma$ is identity

@JyrkiLahtonen Yes, it turns out in that case, that $\theta$ is the only missing value, so it is true

Ok. Is it a problem when $\alpha=\gamma\neq1$ and the equation has no solutions?

@JyrkiLahtonen Zero is no more than one so it's not a problem

There are plenty of easy to describe bijections. The power mapping Robert Israel suggested was also in my mind, but also suitable linearized polynomials might work. As might Dickson polynomials. I did not write that answer, because I am still trying to pin down the exact conditions (like prof Israel's suggestion does require $\alpha^k\neq\gamma$. Mind you, that rules out exactly one choice of $\alpha$ for every $\gamma$, but even so. Can you say how many such exceptions you allow?

@JyrkiLahtonen I'm afraid I don't understand what do you mean by "exceptions"

Exceptions = cases where the number of solutions is something other than $1$. Like $\alpha=\gamma$ with the linear polynomial and $\alpha^k=\gamma$ in prof. Israel's answer.

@JyrkiLahtonen To get rid of such exceptions I demanded that $\gamma$ and $\alpha$ are non-zero and non-identity, so that is not an exception I guess.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Did you have something like this in mind?
For positive integer $k$ the map $f: x \mapsto x^k + \theta$ is one-to-one on $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ if $k$ is coprime to $p^n-1$.  Your equation
$f(\alpha x) = \gamma f(x)$ becomes
$\alpha^k x^k + \theta = \gamma x^k + \gamma \theta$, which has a unique solution if $\alpha^k \ne \gamma$.
